# Bluetooth LE / iBeacons - one radio, multiple broadcasts?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I want to broadcast several BTLE beacons, preferably from a single bluetooth LE radio dongle.

Instead of buying multiple dongles, would it be possible to "pulse" say 5 UUID, major and  minor broadcasts very quickly - every second or even half second on loop so that it would appear there were 5 beacons to a device?

I imagine it would depend on the scanning rate of the handset and other factors... but could it theoretically work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  On iOS devices, I have only been able to switch identifiers once per second, making it only practical to simulate transmitting two iBeacons simultaneously without getting CoreLocation exitedRegion callbacks.

See: [Can I broadcast multiple ibeacon signals from only one bluetooth? and how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21545005/can-i-broadcast-multiple-ibeacon-signals-from-only-one-bluetooth-and-how)

Other BLE capable devices may allow faster switching.

Comment: Thanks David, that's what I needed to know.