# Sending only one iBeacon Packet

Tags: ios, ibeacon

Is it possible to send only 1 iBeacon packet? I have tried using `CBPeripheralManager`,but since there are only 2 method to start and stop advertising, so I can't control how many packet is being broadcast.

What I want to try to do is use an iBeacon packet as a command, instead of just a broadcasting some ID. So I could send 1 iBeacon packet, and if the receiver got the message, it can send back Acknowledgement with another iBeacon packet. The intention is to avoid the pairing of bluetooth to send very simple data. The information will be linked to UUID, major, and minor of the packet.

Or are there better ways to do this than using iBeacon.

Comment: Bluetooth Low Energy doesn't require pairing to exchange data unless you specify that encryption is required.  Discovery, connection and data exchange can take place in a few seconds

Comment: @Paulw11 So that can be done using just CoreBluetooth? I will look into it thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, **you can use iBeacon technology to send information back and forth between two iOS devices** without pairing.  If you have two devices, Device A and Device B, you set both of them up to range for beacons with a common ProximityUUID, say, E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0.  And then you can exchange information in the two byte major and minor fields.

**What you can't do** is control the transmitter enough to send only a single iBeacon advertisement.  The transmitter in iOS sends out 10 advertisement packets per second, so the best you could do is start the transmitter then stop it on a timer about 100ms later.  (You probably shouldn't do this, because there is no guarantee that a single iBeacon advertising packet will be received successfully by the other device -- it may be lost due to a CRC error in the radio noise.  You are probably better off letting the packet continue to transmit until you can confirm from a response from the other device that it was received.)

You can see an example of starting and stopping a transmitter on a timer in my answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21553009/1461050)

Of course, there may be easier and more robust ways of accomplishing what you want with built-in Bluetooth data exchange mechanisms.  But that doesn't change the fact that what you propose is certainly possible.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't since iBeacon is uni-direction device

Comment: I know that iBeacon is unidirectional, I just want to use it in ways it was not design for... seeing if it's possible. But since Paulw11 mentioned that BLE doesn't require pairing, I might look into that first.