# Advertising 2 beacons at the same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

When we start advertising by CBPeripheralManager

```
CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0"] major:1 minor:97 identifier:@"test"];
    NSDictionary *peripheralData = [region peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower:@-60];
    [peripheralManager startAdvertising:peripheralData];
```

the peripheralData is an NSDictionary like this:

```
peripheralData:{
    kCBAdvDataAppleBeaconKey = <e2c56db5 dffb48d2 b060d0f5 a71096e0 00010061 c4>;
}
```

I want advertising 2 beacons at the same time, 
is any way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Try describing better what you need. It's not clear what you have accomplished or how, or what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Apple only allows one `CoreBluetooth` advertisement per app to be active at any given time.  However, you can simulate two beacons advertising by rapidly switching back and forth between which identifier is advertised.

You can see a code sample of how this works in an answer to a similar question here: [Can I broadcast multiple ibeacon signals from only one bluetooth? and how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21545005/can-i-broadcast-multiple-ibeacon-signals-from-only-one-bluetooth-and-how)