# Firebase removeObserver issue swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I my application uses Firebase.
I am currently facing issue with removing observers from DatabaseReference.
On deletion of any value it removes all related(multiple entries) values but when it does not removes the observer for that reference.
When I try to enter same entry next time, it deletes that automatically.
And also RemoveAllObservers() is not working.

```
   func deleteNodeForGatewayFromFirebase(gID:String,ownerID:String)
   {
    ref.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        var loopCount = 1  //  count loops to see how may time trying to loop
        for child in snapshot.children
        {
            print("            ")
            print("            ")
            print("child node ------ loop \(loopCount)")

            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot //each child is a snapshot
            let dict = snap.value as! [String: Any] // the value is a dictionary

            let gId = dict["gatewayId"]
            let nId=dict["nodeId"]
            let owner = dict["ownerId"]


            print("the bits ------")
            print("gatewayId .... \(String(describing: gId))")
            print("nodeId .... \(String(describing: nId))")
            print("ownerId .... \(String(describing: owner))")
            loopCount += 1

            if gID.elementsEqual(gId as! String)
            {
                print("owner found")
                self.ref.child(nId as! String).removeValue { (error, ref) in
                    if error != nil
                    {
                        print("error.... \(String(describing: error))")
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ref.removeValue()
                        print("entry deleted.....")
                    }
                }
                return
            }else
            {
                print("no gateway found")
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: You are overwriting `dataDictionary` with the second beacon's data

Answer (score 2):

While the code shown is flawed in that it immediately overwrites the values of `beaconRegion` and `dataDictionary`, even if these problems are fixed, you still cannot transmit two beacons on iOS at the same time.

iOS simply does not allow this. An app may send out only a single advertisement at a time.   You can, however, simulate transmitting two beacons by quickly alternating between the two.  See my related answer here for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21553009/1461050